# Architectural validation inside controller

Tags: c#, enums

I am looking for the best solution in the given data: one controller with a `Put` method with 2 strings as parameters: `key` and `jsonValue`.

What I have to do: check if `jsonValue` is a valid type of `<key>` and insert into Db.

What I have done is create an enum with all `<key>` possibilities and inside of `Put` I wrote a switch by (`Enum.Key`)

```
Enum.TryParse(key, true, out configType);

switch (configType)
{
    case ConfigType.Configuration:
        if(IsValid(key, value))
            Insert();
        break;

    case ConfigType.Configuration2:
        ...

private bool IsValid(key, value)
{
    Enum.TryParse(key, true, out configType);

        switch (configType)
        {
            case ConfigType.Configuration:
                var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ConfigData>>(value);
                if (!routingConfigurationData.Any())
                    return false;
                break;
            case ConfigType.Configuration2:
                ...

}
```

This is pretty noob thing... I was thinking to create a factory, `ConfigurationFactory` with a method `Create` which will return a generic type based on the key (I can map a key to a type)... but for the `Create` method I need 4-5 classes for each type (e.g. signatures Configuration Create, Configuration2 Create => T Create).

Can you give me some better ideas?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Get rid of large switch case body using Chain Of Responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demonstration of how you can convert you code from switch case to Chain of Responsibility.

The interface and request entity for abstraction of implementation:

```
public interface IProcessor
{
    public bool Process(ProcessRequest request);
    public bool IsResponsible();
}

/// <summary>
/// Add any data required to supply to the processors.
/// </summary>
public class ProcessRequest
{
    public ConfigType Type { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now the base class for doing some plumbing work of doing the business of deciding the executing the derived class methods.

```
public abstract class ProcessorBase : IProcessor
{
    protected IProcessor successor;

    public ProcessorBase(IProcessor successorObj)
    {
        this.successor = successorObj;
    }

    public bool Process(ProcessRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }

        if (this.IsResponsible(request.Type))
        {
            return this.InnerProcess(request);
        }
        else
        {
            return this.successor.Process(request);
        }
    }

    public abstract bool InnerProcess(ProcessRequest request);

    public abstract bool IsResponsible(ConfigType type);
}
```

Now comes your concrete classes which will be actual processor for processing your configuration data.

```
public class Configuration1Processor : ProcessorBase
{
    public Configuration1Processor(IProcessor successor)
        : base(successor) { }
    public override bool InnerProcess(ProcessRequest request)
    {
        var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ConfigData>>(request.Value);
        if (routingConfigurationData.Any())
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override bool IsResponsible(ConfigType type)
    {
        return type == ConfigType.Configuration1;
    }
}

public class Configuration2Processor : ProcessorBase
{
    public Configuration2Processor(IProcessor successor)
        : base(successor) { }

    public override bool InnerProcess(ProcessRequest request)
    {
        // here goes the business logic

        return false;
    }

    public override bool IsResponsible(ConfigType type)
    {
        return type == ConfigType.Configuration2;
    }
}
```

Now we just need a builder method class which will act as factory for creating objects of concrete processor and building a chain.

```
public static class ProcessorChainBuilder
{
    public static IProcessor Build()
    {
        return new Configuration1Processor(
                new Configuration2Processor(null)
            );
    }
}
```

Usage -

```
Enum.TryParse(key, true, out configType);

ProcessorChainBuilder.Build().Process(new ProcessRequest
{
    Type = ConfigType,
    Value = value
});
```

**Note** - at this moment you must be thinking why should I write this much of boilerplate code when a simple switch case can work. Well, this how you build the architecture and write extensible code. Consider a situation, for adding a new processor type you just need create new Concrete processor and add it to the chain in the `Build()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Dictionary<YourEnum,Func<boo>>` and you can call it in your `IsValid` method like `return dictionary[YourEnum]();`

You can choose how to define your `Func<bool>`i.e. in a config class that exposes them, inline in the same class, etc.
Hope this helps.